# How to retain the elements in activity which are dynamically added when I press back button or When I move to parent activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-view, android-navigation

I add the buttons dynamically to an activity, but They are lost When I click back button or when I move to the parent Activity. How to retain them??

Comment: can you leverage cookies? http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/cookie/SetCookie.html just an idea.

Comment: Take a look at SharedPreferences for saving states.

Comment: there is no interaction with server. only on device activity I updated but when I move away from activity, the buttons are lost.

Answer (score 0):

When you press back button the activity is destroyed. SO when you open it again it will be freshly created with default state. If you want to persists the buttons you can save the state to either SharedPreferences or global variables in application class.